# I am unable to install java in my computer what should I do?

Tags: java

When I am installing java a message comes that it is already installed in your computer Would you like to reinstall it, when I click yes a message comes "this action is only valid for products that are currently instlalled

Comment: uninstall and try intalling it again ?

Comment: You might get more sensible answers if you said what version of Java you were trying to install, what kind of installer you were using, and what your OS platform is.

Answer (score 0):

I'd need more info to know your particular situation, but as a boilerplate "get rid of corrupt Java installations" solution, I'd try the following:

1. Get and use [Revo Uninistaller](http://revo-uninstaller.en.softonic.com/) to remove any old versions. The actual uninstall might fail, but Revo is often very good at detecting left-behind stuff and removing it for you. I'd also recommend against using most other "auto/perfect/ultra/[insert marketing gibberish here] Uninstaller" tools, as most of them border on malware-ish. Revo is the only one I've found that works well and consistently.
2. If that fails, follow the [manual removal instructions](http://java.com/en/download/help/manual_regedit.xml).